# Why this array cannot array_sum()?

Tags: php, arrays, sum

```
>Array
>(
>>    [valor_pago_total] => Array
>>>        (
>>>>            [0] => 14.750.861,55
>>>>            [1] => 20.828.923,13
>>>>            [2] => 18.431.681,20
>>>>            [3] => 43.403.452,99
>>>>            [4] => 19.177.285,19
>>>>            [5] => 30.213.514,73
>>>>            [6] => 5.296.079,04
>>>>            [7] => 875.873,76
>>>>            [8] => 254.810,00
>>>)
>>)
```

Why I execute array_sum($valor_pago_total), I get a wrong result. Why?

Comment: Try removing the periods that are separating the thousands and millions.

Comment: Can you post more of your code? It looks like you might be calling `array_sum` on an associative array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the periods by replacing them with nothing, and make the commas into a period to make [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/array_sum) work. Then use [`number_format()`](http://php.net/number_format) to turn it back into your formatted result.

Note that the result will need a 64-bit machine.

```
array_walk( $array['valor_pago_total'], function( &$el) { $el = str_replace( ',', '.', str_replace( '.', '', $el)); });
$sum = array_sum( $array['valor_pago_total']);
var_dump( $sum, number_format( $sum, 2, ',', '.'));
```

This [outputs](http://viper-7.com/z0DxzK):

```
float(153232481.59)
string(14) "153.232.481,59"
```